# Angular 9 Warning typescript.js

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application, angular9

After start application, i have warning

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js 5123:41-60
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Comment: Is this a blank project or you just upgrade from previous version to angular 9 ?

Comment: I upgrade my app to angular 9

Comment: Can you try to run ng build --verbose to see the full error log

Answer (score 1):

Try altering webpack.dev.config.js.

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'doesnotexist/')
)
```

or minimally,

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin( /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/, root('./src'), {} )
```

Comment: I use angular CLI. maybe there is a way to introduce into the angular.json?

Comment: Not sure about angular.json. Try adding the key:

`"preserveSymlinks": true` under build/options in angular.json